# Static Table Outlet Issue

Tags: ios, swift

In my static table I add a referencing outlet to the TableViewController. When I use the back button from my static table to the main viewcontroller I got the Thread 1 queue:com.apple.main-thread(serial) error (when I use the TAB Button I do not get any error). How to correct this error?

```
self    MyAPP.PersonalDetails   0x00007fbec4115b10  0x00007fbec4115b10
UIKit.UITableViewController UITableViewController   0x0000000101a39c00  0x0000000101a39c00
UIViewController    UIViewController        
UIResponder UIResponder     
NSObject    NSObject        
_view   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_tabBarItem id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_navigationItem id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_toolbarItems   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_title  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_nibName    __NSCFString *  "7lP-YV-NNt-view-36j-ce-z6Y"    0x00007fbec41181e0
_nibBundle  NSBundle *  "/Users/hongzhiyuan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8868E556-C18B-43D6-81FA-EA2FA1AC58E4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EBDB6EF8-4D3C-459E-B5F9-F09E73635A10/PP58.app"  0x00007fbec1f06900
_parentViewController   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_childModalViewController   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_parentModalViewController  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_previousRootViewController id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_modalTransitionView    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_modalPreservedFirstResponder   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_dimmingView    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_dropShadowView id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_currentAction  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_storyboard UIStoryboard *  0x7fbec1c6d1a0  0x00007fbec1c6d1a0
_storyboardSegueTemplates   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_externalObjectsTableForViewLoading __NSCFDictionary *  0 key/value pairs   0x00007fbec4118180
_topLevelObjectsToKeepAliveFromStoryboard   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_savedHeaderSuperview   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_savedFooterSuperview   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_editButtonItem id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_searchDisplayController    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_modalTransitionStyle   long long   0   0
_modalPresentationStyle long long   0   0
_lastKnownInterfaceOrientation  long long   1   1
_popoverController  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_containerViewInSheet   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_contentSizeForViewInPopover    CGSize  (width=0, height=0) 
_formSheetSize  CGSize  (width=540, height=620) 
_recordedContentScrollView  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_afterAppearance    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_explicitAppearanceTransitionLevel  long long   0   0
_keyCommands    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_overrideTraitCollections   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_viewControllerFlags    ?       
_retainCount    long long   1   1
_ignoreAppSupportedOrientations bool    false   false
_viewHostsLayoutEngine  bool    false   false
_storyboardIdentifier   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_transitioningDelegate  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance   bool    false   false
_childViewControllers   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_customNavigationInteractiveTransitionDuration  double  0   0
_customNavigationInteractiveTransitionPercentComplete   double  0   0
_customTransitioningView    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_lastNotifiedTraitCollection    UITraitCollection * 0x7fbec1f91780  0x00007fbec1f91780
_presentationController id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_navigationControllerContentOffsetAdjustment    double  0   0
_contentMargin  double  16  16
_topLayoutGuide id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_bottomLayoutGuide  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_topBarInsetGuideConstraint id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_bottomBarInsetGuideConstraint  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_leftLayoutGuide    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_rightLayoutGuide   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_leftMarginGuideConstraint  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_rightMarginGuideConstraint id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_sourceViewControllerIfPresentedViaPopoverSegue id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_modalSourceViewController  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_presentedStatusBarViewController   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_edgesForExtendedLayout unsigned long long  15  15
__embeddedView  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
__embeddingView id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
__embeddedDelegate  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_originalPresentationController id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_temporaryPresentationController    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
__childControllerToIgnoreWhileLookingForTransitionCoordinator   id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_preferredContentSize   CGSize  (width=0, height=0) 
_presentationSizeClassPair  ?       
_navigationControllerContentInsetAdjustment UIEdgeInsets        
_contentOverlayInsets   UIEdgeInsets        
__embeddedViewFrame CGRect  origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=0, height=0)  
_tableViewStyle long long   0   0
_keyboardSupport    id  0x7fbec40d3950  0x00007fbec40d3950
_staticDataSource   id  0x7fbec4114c50  0x00007fbec4114c50
_tableViewControllerFlags   ?       
_filteredDataSource id  0x7fbec4116e10  0x00007fbec4116e10
_filteredDataType   long long   0   0
personalDetailsUsername UILabel!    0x00000001037696b8  0x00000001037696b8
Some    UILabel 0x00000001037696b8  0x00000001037696b8
UIKit.UIView    UIView      
UIKit.UIResponder   UIResponder     
ObjectiveC.NSObject NSObject
```

this is my TableViewController

```
import UIKit

class PersonalDetails: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var personalDetailsUsername: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()               
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
           }    
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: My static table is embedded in a navigation controller which I connect from another table view through "show" segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in this tutorial: [enter link description here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2)

I just add the following code and it is working now.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        println("init PersonalDetails")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```